# How to get rid of initial draw delay in Windows Ink with a drawing tablet?

Tags: windows-10, windows-ink

I have a generic Drawing Tablet that I want to use with Windows 10.

When I plug the tablet to USB port, the Windows Ink icon shows up, indicating that it recognized my drawing tablet. I can draw in applications. It works perfectly fine under Windows' Paint.

However, in 3rd party application, such as Adobe Acrobat Reader, when I try to use the free form drawing. There is a delay. Initially, when I press down with the pen, a circle is shown. I got rid of it by disabling the "Click and Hold" function in Control Panel's "Pen and Touch". But the delay is still there. Here is an example of me trying to draw PacMan. The left is what I want to draw. The right is what I ended up drawing. The software did not pick up that I want to draw a line until I have started drawing.

[image]

You can also see in this short video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haoajtCUkFY&t=38s

The initial stroke is not shown until I drag the pen a bit ("The ink does not come out"). This makes it impossible to do any fine detail work because the application refuses to draw until I drag my pen quite a bit away.

I don't want to use the solution mentioned in the video because I don't have a Wacom tablet and I also want to be able to use any Windows machine without installing driver. Is there a workaround for using Windows Ink? (I already tried "Pen & Windows Ink" setting of "Let me use my pen as a mouse in some desktop apps" to no avail)

Comment: Some workarounds are listed in the comments on [this post](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/delay-before-stroke-begins-drawing-with-wacom-tablet/td-p/10508727). Try to see if any of them helps in your case.

Comment: The solution that worked is to uncheck "Use Windows Ink" in the Wacom driver. I don't have Wacom tablet. I believe that Windows Ink is more than capable of supporting all drawing tablets. There must be some "feature" that is preventing it from working properly.

Comment: There was also this method : [link](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/disable-or-enable-press-and-hold-for-right-clicking-in-win-10.html#:~:text=Steps%20to%20disable%20or%20enable%20press%20and%20hold,Change%20touch%20input%20settings%20or%20Change%20multi-touch%20gesture)

Comment: I already used it to disable the "Click and Hold" circle.

Comment: What I find hard to understand is that it works correctly in Microsoft Paint (not Paint 3D, right?). All I can theorize is that the ancient Microsoft Paint predates Windows Ink and so does not use it, as according to all reports the problem is with Windows Ink. If I'm right, then if your tablet driver doesn't support disabling Windows Ink then you're out of luck. (I don't know if you would accept an answer saying that.)

Comment: Actually, the pen works beautifully in Paint 3D. It even supports Pen Pressure! I guess it is because they are both made by Microsoft. 
I have tried the so called disabling Windows Ink but it seems to simply remove the Windows Ink icon. The lag is still there.

Comment: Does Paint 3D have the lag? Or is it only Adobe?

Comment: No lags in Paint and Paint 3D. But Laggy in Adobe Reader and many other 3rd party apps.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of workarounds I found. But by no means a solution.

**1. Click-hold Draw** - start drawing by dropping the pen tip down twice and hold. Basically, drawing a dot before drawing. This is rather annoying and almost always results in something extra at the starting position.

**2. Draw through Remote Desktop** - connect the drawing tablet to another Windows 10 device and remote desktop to the device which drawing needs to take place. For some reasons, there is no lag in recognizing the pen down event even though the remote device still recognize the input device as a pen.

Answer (score 0):

Particularly for Acrobat Reader, there exist the
[AutoInk plug-in](https://evermap.com/AutoInk.asp),
described as:

> AutoInk™ is a plug-in for Adobe® Acrobat® software. The plug-in provides a set of Acrobat tools (pens and highlighters) for easy annotation of PDF files using pen input. The software is capable of converting handwritten ink into text or sticky notes. Use these tools to write notes, draw, doodle, fill form fields and highlight document content.The plug-in uses smooth inking provided by Microsoft operating system and feels very easy and natural to use with a pen input. It can be also used with any other pointing device such as mouse. The Acrobat's standard "Pencil" tool is designed for a mouse input and does not utilize a pen support that comes with latest operating systems. As the result, AutoInk provides a much better user experience.

Basically, it tries to supply Reader with a modern pen interface.
Their claim, which is probably correct, is that the Pencil tool of
Reader is not correctly designed for a pen, but rather designed
with the mouse in mind.

Extended to the other products in which the pen doesn't work as
good as it could, this would put the blame on an older and lacking
implementation of the pen interface. The products for which the
interface works correctly are more modern products whose developers
correctly understood the difference between pen and mouse and have
interfaced correctly with Windows Ink.